# Code is not working (Matrix keypad)

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, code-review

I am new to Arduino. I am learning from Arduino Cookbook. I was using [tinkercad.com](https://www.tinkercad.com/circuits) for running my Arduino code. But it is not working.
The Serial monitor should show the key which I have pressed on the keypad.
I think there is some syntactical error in the code, I believe the connection is all right. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Please look into this:

```cpp
const char keymap[4][4]={
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
 };
const int rpin[]={9,8,7,6};
const int cpin[]={5,4,3,2};
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Program starting");//for debugging purpose and canbe removed later 
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    pinMode(rpin[i],INPUT);
    digitalWrite(rpin[i],HIGH);
  }
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
    pinMode(cpin[j],INPUT);
    digitalWrite(cpin[j],HIGH);
  }
}
void loop()
{
  char key=getkey();
  if(key!=0)
  {
   Serial.println(key); 
  }  
}
char getkey()
{
  char key=0;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(rpin[i],LOW);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
      if (digitalRead(cpin[j])==LOW)
      key=keymap[i][j];
    }
    digitalWrite(rpin[i],HIGH);
  }
  return key;
}
```

and the connection pic:

[image]

update 1:
[image]

Comment: *Not working* doesn't give us any information. What is not working? How is not working? Is it hardware or software? What is the right result in your opinion?

Comment: The serial monitor is blank.

Comment: The serial monitor should provide the key pressed on it.

Comment: I think so software problem.

Comment: In my opinion, it may be some syntactical error.

Comment: Did you put a resistor in serie with each pin?

Comment: To verify serial communication is working, add this line after your `Serial.begin()` statement: `Serial.println("Program starting");`. Let us know whether you see that line printed when you open the Serial Monitor.

Comment: No, instead i have used internal pull-up.

Comment: @per1234 it is working.

Comment: Please update the question with the full description of what you mean by "not working". Note that you already have 2/5 close votes on this question.

Comment: @per1234 is it okay? Or else should I provide more.

Comment: Add in the Serial test line to your code and note that part is printed so that people know your Serial communications is working correctly. You could add a comment to that line to remind yourself that it's only there for debugging and can be removed later to save memory. Your question should stand by itself without needing to read the information in the comment thread.

Comment: @per1234, Any solution?

Comment: Check pin modes. Should be INPUT_PULLUP and OUTPUT. Also consider debouncing.

Comment: @MikaelPatel, It is still not working.

Comment: "*I think there is some syntactical error in the code*" In that case the code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cited comment:

> Check pin modes. Should be INPUT_PULLUP and OUTPUT. Also, consider
>   debouncing. – Mikael Patel

Please, try:

```
const char keymap[4][4]={
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
 };
const int rpin[]={9,8,7,6};
const int cpin[]={5,4,3,2};
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Program starting");//for debugging purpose and canbe removed later 
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
//Should be INPUT_PULLUP and OUTPUT
    pinMode(rpin[i],OUTPUT);
    pinMode(cpin[i],INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
}
void loop()
{
  char key=getkey();
  if(key!=0)
  {
   Serial.println(key);
   delay(200);              // Also, consider debouncing. 
  }  
}
char getkey()
{
  char key=0;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(rpin[i],LOW);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
      if (digitalRead(cpin[j])==LOW)
      key=keymap[i][j];
    }
    digitalWrite(rpin[i],HIGH);
  }
  return key;
}
```

Comment: I tested this code and it works. And the debouncing time can be lowered to something like 10.

Comment: @gre_gor , for what purpose do you reduce to 10?

Comment: So it's faster to respond.

Comment: @gre_gor , to manually control the buttons, a 0.2-second delay is acceptable. And 0.01-second delay may not be enough.